# Not able to create Point to Site connection with Virtual WAN

Tags: azure-vpn

I've following the steps in the article mentioned below, however, the section where it describes how to **Create a P2S configuration** can't be followed because I don't see an option for **Add point-to-site config** under the Virtual WAN architecture.  Each service is listed as **Registered**.  My VWANs previously existed prior to enabling the point to site configuration and I've even created a brand new VWAN but do not see the option to add a P2S configuration on any of them.  Any ideas?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-wan/virtual-wan-point-to-site-portal

```
    PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Get-AzureRmProviderFeature -ProviderNamespace Microsoft.Network -FeatureName AllowP2SCortexAccess

    FeatureName          ProviderName      RegistrationState
    -----------          ------------      -----------------
    AllowP2SCortexAccess Microsoft.Network Registered       



    PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Get-AzureRmProviderFeature -ProviderNamespace Microsoft.Network -FeatureName AllowVnetGatewayOpenVpnProtocol

    FeatureName                     ProviderName      RegistrationState
    -----------                     ------------      -----------------
    AllowVnetGatewayOpenVpnProtocol Microsoft.Network Registered   

PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Register-AzureRmResourceProvider -ProviderNamespace Microsoft.Network


ProviderNamespace : Microsoft.Network
RegistrationState : Registered
ResourceTypes     : {virtualNetworks, publicIPAddresses, networkInterfaces, interfaceEndpoints...}
Locations         : {West US, East US, North Europe, West Europe...}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, creating a point-to-site connection using Azure Virtual WAN is **Preview** version. You need to navigate to the [Azure portal (Preview)](https://aka.ms/azurevirtualwanpreviewfeatures) and sign in with your Azure account. You will see it.

[image]

Besides, there is an important NOTE:

> This public preview is provided without a service level agreement and
>   should not be used for production workloads. Certain features may not
>   be supported, may have constrained capabilities, or may not be
>   available in all Azure locations. See [the Supplemental Terms of Use for Microsoft Azure Previews](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/support/legal/preview-supplemental-terms/) for details.